# Find one character in a string of any number of characters and return True or False

Tags: python

I'm having trouble returning the correct Boolean value back after checking for all occurrences of a single letter in a string of any length. If the single letter is in the string, I want it to return True. If the single letter is not in the string, I want it to return False. However, when I run it in python, it is just returning back only True or only False and is not accurately checking if the single letter is in the word.

```
def contains_char(any_length: str, single_character: str) -> bool:
    """A way to find one character in a word of any length."""
    assert len(single_character) == 1
    any_length = ""
    single_character = ""
    check_character: bool = False
    i: int = 0 
    while i < len(any_length):
        if any_length[i] == single_character[0]:
            check_character is True
        else:
            i += 1
            alternative_char: int = 0
            while check_character is not True and i < len(any_length):
                if any_length[alternative_char] == single_character[0]:
                    check_character == True
                else:
                    alternative_char += 1
    if check_character is not False:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: why don't you try ```single_character in str```

Comment: @THUNDER07 same thoughts.

Comment: can you provide an example of your expected output? Question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

`in` keyword uses linear search and returns boolean value O(n).

```py
def contains_char(any_length: str, single_character: str) -> bool:
    return single_character in str
```

Linear search follows

```py
def contains_char(any_length: str, single_character: str) -> bool:
    # For each loop iterates through each character in string
    for char in str:
        if char == str:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but Python's `in` operator does this out the box.

```
if single_character in any_length:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: You could quite easily shorten it to `return single_character in any_length`

Answer (score 0):

you are making another mistake in the start of the function:

any_length = ""

after you change the value of any_length your function will never work

Answer (score 0):

`in` Does this for you:

```
def char_in_word(word, char):
    return char in word
```

**However** if you don't want to use builtin, use this:

```
def char_in(word, char):
    for i in word:
        if i == char:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def contains_char(string,character):
    if character in string:
        return True 
    return False
```

Comment: Indentation needs to be fixed